# Humphreys proof check

Tags: lie-algebras, proof-explanation

**Theorem:**
Let $L$ be a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ with $V$ finite dimensional. If $L$ consists of nilpotent endomorphisms and $V\ne 0$, then $\exists v\in V. v\ne 0$, such that $Lv = 0$.

Humphreys gave the following proof on page 13:

[image]

I failed to see how the underlined statement, albeit correct, relates to the proof. Why did Humphreys put this sentence here? Am I missing something?

Comment: mezhang: I see that you have created ([tag:proof-explanation]) tag. I have opened a [thread on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12465/proof-explanation-tag) to discuss whether such tag is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $W$ is not fixed by the action of $z$ 
you can not find the eigenvector for $z$ in $W$ (because it can properly act on $V$ but not on $W$)

Comment: I see now. Somehow I missed it.